# Update and Replace multiple fields but receivng error after each statement

Tags: navicat

I am updating multiple fields and my query works each statement correctly but errors when it goes to the next row.  I comment out the preceeding row and rerun and runs the statement and errors on the next line.
I.e

```
UPDATE mydb
    SET VendorMPD = replace(VendorMPD,'VENDOR Campaign MPD - ','');
    SET VendorMPDHalf = replace(VendorMPDHalf,'Vendor MPD 1/2 Count - ','');
    SET DieselMPD = replace(DieselMPD,'Diesel Pumps - ','')
```

Error that it generates each time:

```
[Err] 42000 - [SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near '='.
```

I had this working perfectly yesterday but needed to add additional fields and when I did this is what started happening.  I looked at the new statements that I entered and with exception to the field names and what they are replacing. The coding is identical.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following syntax to update multiple columns in a single statement:

```sql
UPDATE mydb
SET VendorMPD = replace(VendorMPD,'VENDOR Campaign MPD - ',''),
    VendorMPDHalf = replace(VendorMPDHalf,'Vendor MPD 1/2 Count - ',''),
    DieselMPD = replace(DieselMPD,'Diesel Pumps - ','');
```